# Javascript difference between two words

Tags: javascript

How do you detect the difference between two similar words?

For example:

- `word` compared to `word,` gives `,` as a variable
- `this` compared to `.this` gives `.` as a variable
- `info` compared to `:info,` gives `:` and `,` as a variable

In this case we always know which word is the longer one. And the actual word is always the same for the comparison. It's just that the longer one maybe has some extra characters.

I need to do this using javascript only.

Comment: please add some more examples and their results.

Comment: longer.replace(shorter, '')

Comment: What you are looking for is called [**Levenshtein Distance**](https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927).

Comment: @PraveenKumar that sounds a bit intense - it's not possible with javascript?

Comment: @AmyNeville See my answer. `:)` It's possible. The link I sent you **is** JavaScript. What do you think it is then?

Comment: Link with Possible solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024102/javascript-compare-strings-and-get-end-difference

Comment: @PraveenKumar just testing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, there's a better way, check if the string is a sub-string, and then remove the sub-string from the main string:

```js
function checkDiff(a, b) {
  var big = '', small = '';
  if (a.length > b.length) {
    big = a;
    small = b;
  } else {
    small = a;
    big = b;
  }
  if (big.indexOf(small) != -1) {
    return big.replace(small, "");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

alert(checkDiff("word", "word,"));
alert(checkDiff("this", ".this"));
alert(checkDiff("info", ":info,"));
```

I have added demo for all your cases. It returns the values as a single string, based on the place it has occurred. You can send the output as an array as well, using the `.split()` method.

```js
function checkDiff(a, b) {
  var big = '', small = '';
  if (a.length > b.length) {
    big = a;
    small = b;
  } else {
    small = a;
    big = b;
  }
  if (big.indexOf(small) != -1) {
    console.log(big.replace(small, "").split(""));
    return big.replace(small, "").split("");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

alert(checkDiff("word", "word,"));
alert(checkDiff("this", ".this"));
alert(checkDiff("info", ":info,"));
```

Comment: is it possible to return the start and end variables separately? :0

Comment: @AmyNeville Added `console.log` as well to check in console if it works fine. And it does return the different values as an array, on the basis of the occurrence.

Comment: @AmyNeville Glad it helped. Would you wanna know more information? I mean, do you have any more questions for me?

Answer (score 3):

You could try checking for difference between the array of characters.

```
var shortStr = 'info';
var longStr = ':info,';

console.log(Array.from(longStr).filter(function(c) {
    return Array.from(shortStr).indexOf(c) === -1;
}));
```

Comment: Yea, as I said you, the first code you posted doesn't work. Arrow functions do not work consistently in all the browsers.