# How to get longest substring from array of strings using javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I have array:

```
let arr = ["logerror", "log:today", "log:1"]
```

I am looking for function how to get longest substring from this items.

Result:

```
log
```

Another example:

```
   let arr = ["dog+ěě+", "dog15qwqqq", "dogggggg"]
```

Result:

```
dog
```

Sure, I can write some algorithm, but is there any simple way?

How? Thanks

Comment: What would be a substring in your context?

Comment: See examples in question

Comment: Writing an algorithm looks like a good idea. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Excuse me, maybe you misunderstood me. 
I do not know what it is. 
That's what I'm looking for

Comment: @klugjo 
First I ask more experienced people if there is no function / prototype in javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024102/javascript-compare-strings-and-get-end-difference

Comment: did you use array.sort()

Comment: Longest common substring problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem  No built in function, yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a simple approach:

It sorts the `array` using `sort()` method.

Then, the most important step is to look just at the first and last items.

```js
function commonSubsequence(array){
    let sortedArray = array.sort(); 
    let first = sortedArray[0];
    let last = sortedArray.pop();
    let length = first.length;
    let index = 0;
    
    while(index<length && first[index] === last[index])
        index++;
    return first.substring(0, index);
}
console.log(commonSubsequence(["logerror", "log:today", "log:1"]));
console.log(commonSubsequence(["dog+ěě+", "dog15qwqqq", "dogggggg"]));
```

Comment: Hello Alexandru, this is, what I looking for, thank you for your help.

Comment: @friageac, you're welcome. Don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: Why concat here? sortedArray = array.concat().sort();

Comment: Works fine in this particular case (common substring at the start of the string), but not for all cases.

Comment: @mplungjan in order to protect original array from mutations that sort does with the array

Comment: Ah, ok, Fair enough

Answer (score 4):

If you can phrase your question succinctly, you can often find what to search for.  In this case, it looks like:

"Find the longest common substring from within an array of strings"

A quick google reveals an algorithm for finding the largest common substring between two strings:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring

I don't want to copy the code as written there, as unsure of the copyright, but you could take the implementation and take something that will work with your array.

I would note that for large arrays, this may turn out to be a lengthy operation...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion

```js
function subStrArr(arr) {
  let chars = arr[0].split(""), sub = "";
  for (let i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
    for (let j=1;j<arr.length;j++) {
      if (arr[j].indexOf(chars[i])==-1) return sub;
    }
    sub+=chars[i];
  }
}  

let arr1 = ["logerror", "log:today", "log:1"];
let arr2 = ["dog+ěě+", "dog15qwqqq", "dogggggg"];

console.log(subStrArr(arr1))
console.log(subStrArr(arr2))
```

Comment: Works fine in this particular case (common substring at the start of the string), but not for all cases.

Comment: OP wanted from start - otherwise the algorithm is [MUCH more complex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#JavaScript)

Comment: Yep, just wanted to say the same (maybe i should rephrase my self) - code works if common substring is always at the start of the string. :)

Answer (score 1):

After some looking around I went for the [string-algorithms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-algorithms) npm package, which did the job nicely for me.

From the docs:

```js
import { longestCommonSubstring } from 'string-algorithms';

const strings = [
  '12apple',
  '3apple4',
  'apple56'
];

console.log(longestCommonSubstring(strings));
```

> produces the output apple.

Answer (score 0):

without DP approach

```
var lcs = function (n, m) {
    let lcs = 0 //to store longest common substring
    let s1 = n.length
    let s2 = m.length

    for(let i = 0;i < s1;i++){
        for(let j = 0; j< s2;j++){
            let track = 0
            //if letter are same, do while to check next letter
            if(n[i] == m[j]){
                while(i + track < s1 && j + track < s2 && n[i + track] == m[j + track]){
                    track += 1 // to track
                    if (lcs < track) {
                        lcs += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return lcs;
};

var m = "abcdxyz"
var n = "xyzabcd" // 4

// var m = "dadef"
// var n = "adwce"//2

// var m = "acdghr";
// var n = "bgh"; //2

// var m = "A"
// var n = "A" //1
console.log(lcs(m, n));
```