# Subtract two strings in jS

Tags: javascript

I want to find the difference between two strings in Javascript.

Given two strings

```
 var a = "<div>hello</div><div>hi</div><div>bye/</div>";
 var b = "<div>hello</div><div>hi</div>";
```

The result should be `"<div>bye</div>".`

Like in formula:

```
var result = a - b;
```

& I need this implementation in Javascript (Is there any default method is available for this in JS??)

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Already addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024102/javascript-compare-strings-and-get-end-difference

Comment: Is this for a string or specifically for DOM nodes? And there's not enough details about what you expect. Is this only for a starts with b? If b is `<div>hello</div><div>bye</div>` does that mean a-b is `<div>hi</div>`?

Regardless, I feel like this isn't the right approach to your problem.

Answer (score 21):

You can obtain the desired output with

`var s = a.replace(b, '')`

Comment: wouldn't work the same if you change the order of divs.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like an [x/y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But in any case, I’ll try to help you out.

We want to find the location of `b` within `a`.

```
var start = a.indexOf(b);
var end = start + b.length;
```

Now put it together.

```
return a.substring(0, start - 1) + a.substring(end);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var a = "<div>hello</div><div>hi</div><div>bye/</div>";
var b = "<div>hello</div><div>hi</div>";

c = a.substring(b.length)

console.log(c);
```

Comment: Your answer only works for cases where the `a` starts with `b`, if `b` is nested in `a`, this will not work. Although it works for the example given by the author, questions like this on SO should be answered generally