# Javascript highlight differences on a toggle switch

Tags: javascript

I am interested in creating a javascript toggle ability to highly the differences in rows.
https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=9847&idPhone2=9536#diff-*,*,*

so here is a base sand box.
http://jsfiddle.net/5b37w6of/3/

I've seen some functions that could evaluate differences in text -- but I think with this it needs to go over each row - and on the differences apply a span tag around the different bits - then remove the span if the toggle is set back.
[Javascript compare strings and get end difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024102/javascript-compare-strings-and-get-end-difference) -- but there could be more than 2 cols

```
var s1 = "The quick brown fox",
  s2 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the fence",
  string1 = new Array(),
  string2 = new Array(),
  diff = new Array(),
  longString;

string1 = s1.split(" ");
string2 = s2.split(" ");

if (s1.length > s2.length) {
  longString = string1;
} else {
  longString = string2;
}

for (x = 0; x < longString.length; x++) {
  if (string1[x] != string2[x]) {
    diff.push(string2[x]);
  }
}

document.write("The difference in the strings is " + diff.join(" "));
```

- 

here is a demo with the differences npm -- http://jsfiddle.net/8c4nt2e1/1/

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here. To compare strings take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff. There is an option to compare by characters.

Comment: you have a row of data --- looking at 4 different computers - and so you are looking at specs. You want to flick a toggle switch that will highlight the differences. --- so you need to compare the strings in ALL 4 cols -- wrap the differences with a span -- then if the user toggles the switch again - take off the span -- without destroying markup that was already once there - formatting

Comment: Use an HTML attribute on your span so you can find it back e.g. `<span data-diff></span>`

Comment: implementation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, use [npmjs.com/package/diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff) to handle characters differentiation and use a HTML custom attribute e.g. `data-diff` to find back your `span` element.

```js
document.getElementById('show-diff').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const diff = Diff.diffChars(document.getElementById('input-1').value, document.getElementById('input-2').value);
  const output = diff.reduce((result, change) => {
    if (change.added) return result + '<span data-diff="added">' + change.value + '</span>';
    if (change.removed) return result + '<span data-diff="removed">' + change.value + '</span>'
    return result + change.value;
  }, '');

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
  console.log(output);
});

document.getElementById('hide-diff').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const output = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output.replace(/<span data-diff=["'](?:added|removed)["']>(.+)<\/span>/gi, '$1');
});
```

```css
[data-diff="added"] {
  color: green;
}

[data-diff="removed"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/diff@4.0.2/dist/diff.min.js"></script>

<div><input id="input-1" value="The quick brown fox" /></div>
<div><input id="input-2" value="The quick brown fox jumped over the fence" /></div>

<button id="show-diff">Show diff</button>
<button id="hide-diff">Hide diff</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: handle multiple inputs? but it needs to touch the cols themselves - highlight the differences

Comment: I'm not doing it for you. I gave you more of what you need to solve your problem. Figure the rest by yourself.

Comment: right - so I am not sure if this is the correct thing to go for then if it can't handle multiple lines - and modify the seen content in the row directly and back again

Comment: I need this fleshed out to fulfil the bounty - looking for a canonical answer: